# Twig: Javascript inclusion order

Tags: php, twig

A little issue that has been bugging me; with PHP & twig

I need to include javascripts in a certain order

This is my layout flow

- app_layout.twig - this is my core app layout with headers and footers, with its own js as well
- module.twig - I extend app_layout.twig here. Module has its own set of javascript files
- sub-module.twig - This is included inside module and has its own js.

How can include javascript inside sub-module that will add at the end of the page?

```
Example module.twig

    {% extends "app_layout.twig" %} 
      <-- some html -->
      {% include "submodule.twig" %}
      {%block js_includes%}
       <-- some js includes here -->
      {%endblock%}
      {%block sub_js_includes%}
      {%endblock%}


    Example submodule.twig
    <-- some html -->
    {%block sub_js_includes %}
     <-- js for submodule
    {%endblock%}
```

But the sub_js_includes are included even before js_includes. How can i make sure the subjs includes are indeed after the module js includes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. A include does exactly that, including. 
I think you are looking for [parent](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html) function. Then you can restructure your coode to extend more then once.

**Example module.twig**

```
{% extends "app_layout.twig" %} 
    {%block js_includes %}
        <-- some js includes here -->
    {%endblock%}
{%endblock%}
```

**Example submodule.twig**

```
{% extends "module.twig" %} 
    {%block js_includes %}
        {{ parent() }}
        <-- more js includes here -->
    {%endblock%}
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Thanks Jahns for pointing it out. Let me see if i can re-organize the structure.

Comment: The idea is, you simply put a js block at the end of the site in your main template and extend this block in lower templates.